# BIDS Installation

Tags: bids

I Need to Get BIDS Installed. I Have got VS2010 and Sql Server Developer Edition already Installed . However BIDS Comes as an VS2008 addon. So I Got it installed too . However I still dont find any BIDS program under VS2008 folder or find any upgrade option in Sql server installation Setup .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BIDS is installed under Microsoft SQL Server *version*.

Comment: Ya I had not got the Visual Studio 2008 SP1 Installed . Once that update was installed . BIDS Showed up among the options . Anyways thanks.